# issues with iterating objects in *ngFor in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array in `subscribe` like `this.Term` and if I console, it looks like

```
[Discount Condition:Array(3), Stay Consition:Array(2)]
Discount Condition:Array(3)
0:object
   EventType:"success"
   Heading:"Discount Condition"
   Help:"Terms"
1:object
   EventType:"success"
   Heading:"Discount Condition"
   Help:"Terms"
2:object
   0:object
   EventType:"success"
   Heading:"Discount Condition"
   Help:"Terms"

Stay Condition:Array(2)
0:object
1:object
```

I'm trying to print it in component html like ,

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Term">
     {{item.Heading}}
</div>
```

If I check using inspect elements it says

```
<!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->
```

Here is the function

```
getTerms(){
    this.quoteService.getTerms()
    .subscribe(
      terms => {
        this.terms = terms.resultData.Terms;
        this.notes = terms.resultData.ImpNotes;
        this.exclusions = terms.resultData.Exclusions;
        var arr=[];
        var strHeading;
        for(let i=0;i<this.terms.length;i++) {
          strHeading=this.terms[i].Heading;
          if (arr.indexOf(strHeading) >= 0) {
            this.uniqTerm[strHeading].push(this.terms[i]);
          } 
          else {
            if (!this.uniqTerm[strHeading])
               this.uniqTerm[strHeading] = [];
               this.uniqTerm[strHeading].push(this.terms[i]);
               this.Term.push(this.uniqTerm);
               arr.push(strHeading);
          }         
        }        
        console.log(this.Term);
      },
      response => {
        if (response.status == 404) {
          //this.router.navigate(['NotFound']);
        }
      });
  }
```

Can anyone please point where am I going wrong?

Comment: That's not enough information. Please provide more code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer code updated in question, please check

Answer (score 1):

`this.Term` appears to be an array of arrays.

something like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Term[0]">
     {{item.Heading}}
</div>
```

would be a dirty check to see whether your data is correct.

Then if you want to iterate over these arrays;

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Term">
     <div *ngFor="let elem of item">
           {{elem?.Heading}}
     </div>
</div>
```

might work.

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya does your objects inside the array have a `Heading` property ? Can you include a `console.log` from those objects?

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya I'm having a hard time understanding your data structure :-)  Are `Stay Consition` and `Discount Condition` arrays or objects?

Comment: sorry about that,  if I `console.log(typeof(this.Term));` then it returns `object`

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya `*ngFor` only iterates on arrays not objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146506/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-echonax).

Comment: I know but it is not giving error either, earlier in other case if I try to iterate over object it was giving error like, ngFor only iterate over array